# using a while loop as a function

Tags: python-3.x

ok i have a problem that has stumped me. create a program uses a while loop in a function to ask for values in a range (0-30) exits on a negative.
Passes said value in range to a function that concatenates together that number of asterisks assigning it to a variable (nStars).
Return the value to the calling program where the string is assigned to StarsOut.
Finally pass the variable StarsOut to a third function that prints the string.

This is what i have and atm it only functions after i exit the loop and i'm not sure how to fix it.

```
    def Function1(num):
        global nStars
        nStars=num
    def Function2(Stars):
        global nStarsOut
        nStarsOut=nStars
    def Function3(final):
        for r in range(final):
           print("*")
    def Loop():
        Number=1
        while Number!=-999:
            Number=int(input("Enter an integer between 0 and 30(-999 to exit): "))
            if 0<=Number<=30:
                Function1(Number)
            if Number<0 or Number>30:
                print("invalid")

    Loop()
    Function2(nStars)
    Function3(nStarsOut)
```

Comment: also atm ot never converts the original value to a string like its suppose to do, as i am unsure how to make it do that and still have a useable value for later

Comment: So to my understanding, you want to print '*' right after the user enters a input without exiting the loop??

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [break](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm) statement for python.

Comment: wow its as simple as that?? amazing with that break it runs like its suppose to.  now if only it was that easy to make the first function do what its suppose to do "Passes said value in range to a function that concatenates together that number of asterisks assigning it to a variable (nStars)"

Comment: `nStars = num * '*'`

Comment: wow you guys make things seem so easy, it took me several hours to get what i had that only partially worked

Comment: So, yeah. Tony beat me to it. The way you have written the instructions, nStars would be the integer, and StarsOut would be your string.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop You are calling only `Function1()` which assigns `nStars=num` then the loop starts over again. So right now `Function2()` is only executed when u have already left the loop. Add `break` inside the loop after calling `Function1()` because You don't want to start the loop again after You get valid input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print `*` right after the user has given an input without exiting the loop. I think you dont need the functions in the first place, you could do something like this:

```
def Loop():
    Number=1
    while Number!=-999:
        Number=int(input("Enter an integer between 0 and 30(-999 to exit): "))
        if 0<=Number<=30:
          for r in range(Number):
            print("*")
        if Number<0 or Number>30:
            print("invalid")
```

Then you can even skip the unnecessary functions, in my opinion.

Update:

But if you want to take an input, then generate that many `*` and save them up and print them all at once after you exit the loop, you can do it like this:

```
def Function1(num):
  global nStars
  nStars=nStars + num*'*'
def Function2(t):
  print(t)
def Loop():
  Number=1
  while True:
    Number=int(input("Enter an integer between 0 and 30(negative values to exit): "))
    if 0<=Number<=30:
      Function1(Number)
    if Number<0:
       break
    if Number > 30:
       print("invalid")
nStars = ''
Loop()
Function2(nStars)
```

Comment: I'd love to skip the functions it would have made it simple but the way they want it set-up uses function so i have to go by my sheet

Comment: Are you trying to do this by chance, like collecting the inputs and generate that many `*` on each input and add them to a string and then print them all at once??